# Catch block not firing all statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

**My goal** is to test my function: `fetchStats`

**Expected Results:** It `console.logs` the error and a failure message. and sets `_isFetching` to false.

**Actual Results:** The error is caught but console.logs not fired and isFetching is not set.

Code below:

`fetchStats:`

```
fetchStats() {
    this._isFetching = true;
    // fetch stats after building url and replacing invalid characters
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      await API.fetchStats(this.rsn)
        .then(jres => {
          this.skills = jres.main.skills;
          this._isFetching = false;
          resolve('success');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          console.log('error retreiving stats');
          this._isFetching = false;
          reject('Failed to retreive stats');
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this._isFetching = false;
        });
    });
  }
```

The test:

```
it("catches thrown errors", () => {
      this.apiFetchStats.throws(new Error());
      const player = Player.fromJSON(
        JSON.stringify({
          rsn: 'rsn',
          skills: {
            overall: { level: 2000 },
            attack: { attack: {} },
            defence: { defence: {} },
         },  
        })  
      );
      sinon.spy(console, "log");
      player.fetchStats();
      expect(this.apiFetchStats).to.be.calledOnce;
      expect(this.apiFetchStats).to.have.thrown();
      expect(console.log).to.have.been.calledTwice;
      expect(player.isFetching()).to.be.false;
      console.log.restore();
    });
  });
```

The first two expects pass fine, signalling that it has been called and did throw so it should be in catch block but console.log was not called and isFetching was not set. Does anyone have an idea on what is going wrong?

Resolved by adding expectations to `.then` of `player.fetchStats` like so:

```
  player.fetchStats().then(() => {
    expect(this.apiFetchStats).to.be.calledOnce;
    expect(this.apiFetchStats).to.have.thrown();
    expect(console.log).to.have.been.calledTwice;
    expect(player.isFetching()).to.be.false;
  })  
  .finally(() => { console.log.restore(); });
```

Comment: if fetchStats returns a promise you need to await it

Comment: `await player.fetchStats` caused an error `API.fetchStats.then` is not a function. but this led me down the right track. Instead of running fetchStats then immediately "expecting" I needed to `.then` player.fetchStats and expect in there. I have edited it into the question.

Comment: if you post an answer I will accept it as you led me down the path to the correct answer @damian

Comment: Wrapping one promise inside of another `new Promise()` is a complete anti-pattern.  Just return the promise you already have.  Don't wrap another one around it.  And, if you want the returned promise to remain rejected even though you have a `.catch()` handler, just rethrow the error inside the `.catch()` handler.  Do not rewrap promises unnecessarily.